# Getting start date and end date value from view to controller without using model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view which contain two fields start date, end date of type Date and button on button click controller return collection .
and a model of I Enumerable type.
I want to get start date and end date value in controller and process my stuff and return to the same view and display here all collection using foreach loop

Here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<EChallan.DataModel.CustomModel.OffenceCodeByDateCM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OffenceCodeByDate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2 style="color:White">Offence Code By Date</h2>
<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">


    <table>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("OffenceCodeByDate", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
        {

             @*@String.Format("{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}", item.Documentdate)*@        
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <span class="login-text">Star Date:</span> <span class="inpt-css">
                </td>
                @*<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME, new { @required = "true" })</td>*@
                <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @required = "true", type = "date" , value="startdate" })
                </td>



                <td> <button id="btnsubmit" type="submit" name="Report" class="btn btn-large btn-info pull-right">Report </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

and model

```
public class OffenceCodeByDateCM
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Tickets { get; set; }
    public int Fine { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your model, show your view

Comment: Do you mean you want to select 2 dates in a view, and then in the controller, return a collection of `OffenceCodeByDateCM` that is filtered based on those dates?

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke
yes i really want do that

Comment: OK, I will post an answer with a suggestion a bit later, but you should update you question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: okay me waiting you answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating a view model containing properties for the dates and the collection

```
public class OffenceCodeVM
{
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<OffenceCodeByDateCM> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the controller GET method

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
  OffenceCodeVM model = new OffenceCodeVM()
  {
    StartDate = startDate,
    EndDate = endDate,
    Items = // populate this from the database based on the method parameters
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

then in the view

```
@model yourAssembly.OffenceCodeVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("OffenceCodeByDate", "Report", FormMethod.Get)) // note the FormMethod.Get
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate)
  <input type="submit" .../>
}
@foreach(var item in Model.Items)
{
  .... // render the elements to display your properties of each OffenceCodeByDateCM object
}
```

As an alternative you may want to consider using ajax to pass the dates to another method which returns a partial view of the 'report'. It will improve performance since only part of the view needs to be updated.

Comment: exactly that what i want very help for me

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to controller without using model like below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OffenceCodeByDate", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
{
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @required = "true", type = "date" , value="startdate" })
}
```

In Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OffenceCodeByDate(string StartDate)
{
      return View();
}
```

Comment: but i want to get these value from control not static

Comment: What control you want  to get it

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StartDate , new { @required = "true",type="date" })